# OpenSSL AES-CBC-256 Encryption SALT ERROR

Tags: openssl

in https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Enc it stated that in order for me to give in salt value for openssl to do encryption, i have to specify

> With -S salt it is possible to explicitly give its value (in hexadecimal).

And this is what i did, `openssl enc -aes256 -base64 -iv 40AA481FEB82C35D1CF35CD1C0468C2F -S F80EC003AA550000 -K DD9F547EDAA1373F85EB98D0608E2DCA66D7426F31FC66B87953799153844 -p -in hi.txt -out cipher.enc` in openssl

And the -p shows salt to be different value that what i give. Is there a reason why? And if so, how to i explicitly define my salt to openssl?

Comment: I've found that it never change the salt even if given the specified salt. Either way, it still works after i specified the other parameters. Thank you all for contributing. I will leave this open in case anyone can provide a better solution for everyone to see.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're given the raw byte key (option `-K`) to openssl, the salt given in argument is not used.

Salt is used to compute the raw byte key based on a (string) password.

For example you can use option `-k` and provide your password together with the salt:

```
$ openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -iv 40AA481FEB82C35D1CF35CD1C0468C2F -S F80EC003AA550000 -k "mypassword" -p  -base64 <<< "hello"
salt=F80EC003AA550000
key=4B3178E6330155D5CB9D5D0A17C1853526D9A38BB990671029730D9202A2E89D
iv =40AA481FEB82C35D1CF35CD1C0468C2F
U2FsdGVkX1/4DsADqlUAACw5WayUfFeijGYjYaI/SQw=
```